# Where did the term "Zombie" originate from?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie, terminology

As I said above, where did the term "**Zombie**" originate from? Why can't we just call them the "reanimated"?

Comment: Have you tried googling "zombie" etymology?

Comment: No what is Etymology?(<-that is why i didnt google it)

Comment: Etymology is the study of the history and origin of words. Some dictionaries, such as the (unabridged) *Oxford English Dictionary* give etymologies, including language of origin and dates of recorded use for different meanings.

Comment: Tagging this "the walking dead" seems odd since they make a specific point to not ever use that word in the show or comics.

Comment: oh true... I just thought someone who also watches the show would see this question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the etymology (origin) of a real-world word.

Comment: @Richard The use of the term "zombie" in the real world differs in important ways from the way it is used in SFF. See for example, my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [In Haitian folklore, a zombie (Haitian Creole: zonbi, Haitian French: zombi) is an animated corpse raised by magical means, such as witchcraft.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie) [Wikipedia]

But this historical meaning has a factual basis in social relationships and ritual within a specific religious context. (For an easy read on the topic, try Zora Neal Hurston's *Tell My Horse*.) The 20th century popular media variations (i.e. genesis magical, divine, or pathogenic?, fast zombies versus slow zombies, etc.) are more a construction of Hollywood (*a la* the 1932 Bella Lugosi film [*White Zombie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Zombie_%28film%29), and especially the [Romero zombie cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead_%28film_series%29), including [adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Dead_%282004_film%29)), comic books (e.g. [*Tales of the Zombie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_the_Zombie), etc.), and other popular media and cultural phenomena (e.g. [zombie flash mobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_walk), and [video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us)) that borrows a very rough approximation to the Haitian phenomenon, but mostly builds off iterations of its own cultural reinterpretion.

Comment: I add a tongue in cheek comment on my own answer to say that *fast zombies* are *clearly* not zombies at all, but *ghasts* (in D&D terms ;).

Comment: lol ok. sorry too young to be playing D&D tho...im more into the last of us

Comment: Too young?!? Young'un, I started playing D&D when I was 9. ;)

Comment: I mean it is an old game and I'm a younger guy...not saying you're old or anything...:3

Comment: I think *The Last of Us* is the only video game I watched a full walk through of. (I don't really play video games much). The cordicepes-zombie world of the game is interesting.

Answer (score 3):

From Merriam-Websster

> Origin of ZOMBIE
>
> Louisiana Creole or Haitian Creole zonbi, of Bantu origin; akin to
> Kimbundu nzúmbe ghost First Known Use: circa 1871

and From Wikipedia

> **Etymology**
>
> The English word "zombie" is first recorded in 1819, in a
> history of Brazil by the poet Robert Southey, in the form of
> "zombi".[2] The Oxford English Dictionary gives the origin of the word
> as West African, and compares it to the Kongo words "nzambi" (god) and
> "zumbi" (fetish).